# Cannot Use Microsoft Chart Control on a 64 bit Operating System

Tags: asp.net, 64-bit, charts, 32-bit, mschart

I am having issues running the chart control on our 64 bit machine. I get the following error...

> Could not load file or assembly 'AspnetChart' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

The machine I am running this on is a Windows Server 2003 Enterprise x64 Edition SP2 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5405 @ 2.00 GHz w/ 4.00 GB RAM

The chart control works fine on our 32 bit Windows XP Professional SP3 and Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition SP2 machines, but not when deployed to the 64 bit machine.

I tried to change the Platform target to x86, but that didn't seem to help. I also tried signing the dll and putting it in the GAC, but that didn't help.

Any thoughts, suggestions?

Comment: Just a reminder, the errormessage also contains "... or one of its dependencies"

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you have a 32 bit DLL.  In IIS 7 it's possible to [run 32-bit and 64-bit processes simultaneously](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/IIS/21_IIS7_-_Running_32-bit_and_64-bit_ASPNET_versions_at_the_same_time_on_different_worker_processes.aspx).  But in IIS 6 you can only do one or the other.  For running 32-bit applications on IIS 6 (64-bit windows) check out this [Microsoft article](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/13f991a5-45eb-496c-8618-2179c3753bb0.mspx?mfr=true).